# Spring FeignClient: How to configure a load balancer like Ribbon

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am using Spring FeignClient and have to support a load balancing like Spring Ribbon provides.

```
@FeignClient(name = "testClient", url = "${test.url}", configuration = TestConfig.class)
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = 
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public interface TestClient {
 }

public class TestConfig{
 @Bean
 public Client feignClient() {
    return new ApacheHttpClient(getHttpClient());
  }
}
```

I want to understand how can I add Ribbon to the configuration.

Comment: One way to work with Ribbon is to make your request to a naming server instead of a URL, also it is more flexible than including all your hosts in a properties file.

Comment: Please check [this article](http://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka) related on how to configure the naming server and you will get the idea

Comment: @ngueno but we are not using Eureka

Comment: For this case probably Matt solution will attend you, but every time you will have to update the properties file with your servers addresses

Comment: I would add that if you do want to include a list of servers in the properties/yml file then you should look a way to be flexible with the list of servers by using config service and @ refreshscope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the configurations properties like so:

```
hello-service:
  ribbon:
    eureka:
      enabled: false
    listOfServers: localhost:8090,localhost:9092,localhost:9999
```

without eureka:

```
stores:
  ribbon:
    listOfServers: example.com,google.com
```

[ribbon docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#spring-cloud-ribbon-without-eureka)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I am sorry but didn't get the solution. Also, we are not using Eureka

Comment: [Link to the docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html#spring-cloud-ribbon-without-eureka) on how to use Ribbon without Eureka